# Creating Doctrine query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have my Entity Entry and would like to return a count count for dates and number of entries for the last 15 days and display the data in a chart.

However, the DQL is writing is somehow failing not bringing the result I want and would appreciate if anyone might assist.

Here's the query I want to achieve in mysql

```
SELECT count(*) as total, DATE_FORMAT(e.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as date  FROM entries e WHERE e.created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY date
```

Here is what I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as total, DATE_FORMAT(e.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as date  FROM entries e WHERE e.created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY date";
    $q = $this->em->createQuery($sql);
    $registered = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ago = new \DateTime('15 days ago');
$now = new \DateTime('now');

$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('e.created_at');
$qb->from('entries', 'e');
$qb->where('e.created_at BETWEEN :ago AND :now')
$qb->setParameter('ago', $ago->format('Y-m-d'))
$qb->setParameter('now', $now->format('Y-m-d'));

// get results
$dates = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

*Notice that `format()` method should match your column date format*

`$dates` is an array that contains the matched dates. If you want you know to know the count then you do:

```
$count = count($dates);
```